# GCP - VM instance missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I had a wordpress deployment on GCP using "Click to Deploy". A few months back there was some issue with the billing account, which was corrected recently. But now the VM instance is no longer showing in the list.

I can still see the wordpress deployment under deployment manager. It also shows the VM name there, clicking on it, it redirects to the VM instances page with the error "Failed to load"

Comment: then open a support ticket on GCP they can solve issues directly ;)

Comment: This is a community web site, not an official Google support channel. Contact Google directly to resolve this issue.

Comment: If the problem was more than 30 days ago, the instance has been deleted. You must create a new instance and set up the applications again.

Comment: The linked account does not have a paid support, hence community help was the only option

Answer (score 1):

Although VM gets deleted you can see the wordpress deployment properties in the deployment manager. Delete the wordpress properties in the deployment manager and redeploy it.

If your Compute Engine Instance was deleted, it is not possible to restore [it](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#if_i_accidentally_delete_my_instance_can_i_retrieve_it). During
the creation of the Instance you could configure deletion rules to keep the boot
disk when the instance is deleted. This can be configured in the submenu
“Management, security, disks, networking, sole tenancy” in the Disks section.

However, if you have a snapshot of the [disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots), you can create a new instance
from that snapshot, or, if the disk from the original instance was not deleted
(as I explained above), you can create a new [instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) from that disk.

As a note, there are settings for preventing accidental deletion of [instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion)
which may also be useful.

Also, if you have a machine [image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images), you can recreate an identical
instance from it. A machine image stores all the configuration, metadata,
permissions, and data from one or more disks required to recreate an identical
virtual machine [instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-instance-from-machine-image#create-instance-from-image-gcloud).